# How to organize multiple executable F# files into one VS solution?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, f#

I'm learning F# recently and using it to solve problems like "Haskell 99 problems" as a practice. I'm coding with Visual Studio 2013 Community on Windows.

My problem is that I don't know how to organize all my sources codes in one solution/project.

In other languages like Ruby, I could organize my source codes like:

```
haskell99/
    problem1.rb
    problem2.rb
    ...
    problem99.rb
```

I could code and execute each source file independently in any IDE.

But if I organize my F# source codes in a similar way in Visual Studio:

```
Solution 'Haskell99'
    Project 'Haskell99'
        problem1.fs
        problem2.fs
        ...
        problem99.fs
```

I can not just switch to a source code and press Ctrl+F5 to execute it. If I do so, all the source codes contained in this Solution will be compiled to one single .exe file.

I also tried other ways like one project per problem:

```
    Solution 'Haskell99'
        Project 'Problem1'
            Program.fs
        Project 'Problem2'
            Program.fs
        ...
        Project 'Problem99'
            Program.fs
```

Or F# scripts in a solution:

```
    Solution 'Haskell99'
        Project 'Haskell99'
            problem1.fsx
            problem2.fsx
            ...
            problem99.fsx
```

They all not work.

Is there any best practice to achieve this:

```
Switch to a source file by double click it; 
Then press Ctrl + F5 to ONLY compile and execute this source file.
```

Thanks for your response in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to start a debugger, then your one-project-per-problem is the only option.  It's one extra step, but if you follow http://blog.michaelckennedy.net/2007/07/30/visual-studio-tricks-series-1-set-as-startup-project/ to add a hotkey to set-as-startup-project, then your process is

- double-click the source file
- hit ctrl-shift-p to set that as startup project
- hit F5 to compile and execute the project with debugger attached

Or if you don't need the file open in the editor, it's just

- single-click the project
- hit ctrl-shift-p to set that as startup project
- hit F5 to compile and execute the project with debugger attached

Comment: This solution is very helpful. Thanks. I'm going to organize my code like this.

Answer (score 3):

Install [F# power tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/136b942e-9f2c-4c0b-8bac-86d774189cff), and when you have an .fsx file open in your editor, there's an option to "Execute in Interactive".  You can map this to any key combo you want.

Comment: Thanks. I tried F# power tools and now I can execute code separately. 
But seems I can't debug a `.fsx` file.